# jQuery version in Mobilefirst

Tags: jquery, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Mobile First 7.1.0 and v8 is bundled with which JQuery version?

how can we check the jQuery files version in MobileFirst?

Answer (score 0):

To get started with IBM MobileFirst v8, you need to install the Cordova CLI. These applications can be further enhanced by using various 3rd party frameworks and tools such as Ionic, AngularJS, jQuery Mobile and many more.

I suggest that you will start getting familiar with the MobileFirst Foundation v8...

Product overview: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/product-overview/
Upgrading/Migrating: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/
Application development: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.9.1 of jQuery is used in MFP 8.0 and 7.1